# Android Sim Change Detect, error in Log.e

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver

I have error when refer to LogCat. I have store the storedsimcard(1st) and compare with currentsimcard(2nd), if sim serial is different, logcat will print out sim changed. But i had problem with my service when i run it. Below is my code

**LogCat showing**

```
Tag SimSerial::            8944110065486249080  
Tag Current Sim Serial::   8944110065486249080  
Tag Sim Status             Sim no changed !!!  

Tag SimSerial::            8944110065486249080   
Tag Current Sim Serial::   8944110065486249080   
Tag Sim Status             Sim changed !!!
```

First part is correct, but the second part Sim Status should no "Sim no changed" as well.
Does anyone know where is the error ?

**BootCompleteReceiver**

```
public class BootCompleteReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {   

    Context context;
    SharedPreferences settings;
    public static final String PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefsFile";

     @Override  
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {  

        Intent service = new Intent(context, MyService.class);  
        context.startService(service);   

    }  

}
```

**MyService**

```
public class MyService extends Service {  

    String storedSimSerial;
    String currentSimSerial;

    @Override  
    public void onCreate() {  
        super.onCreate();    
    }  

    @Override  
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {  

        Toast.makeText(this, "Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        TelephonyManager telephoneMgr = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        storedSimSerial = telephoneMgr.getSimSerialNumber();
        Log.e("SimSerial::",storedSimSerial);

        TelephonyManager tmMgr = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        currentSimSerial = tmMgr.getSimSerialNumber();
        Log.e("Current Sim Serial::",currentSimSerial);

        if(currentSimSerial==storedSimSerial)
        {
            Log.e("Sim Status","Sim no changed !!!");
        }             
        else
            Log.e("Sim Status","Sim changed !!!");

        return Service.START_STICKY;  
    }  

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {

        super.onDestroy();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Service Destroy", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override  
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {  
        return null;  
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write your `if` like this:

```
    if(currentSimSerial.equals(storedSimSerial))
    {
        Log.e("Sim Status","Sim no changed !!!");
    }             
    else
        Log.e("Sim Status","Sim changed !!!");
```

When you use `==` you compare Object references, not content which rarely works for Strings.

Comment: Thank you. it solved ! Cant believe such a small error wasted me hour to find answer.